# How to select input element with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I just cannot find working way to select this element, tried by CSS and xpath, but nothing works.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

This does not work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='theform']/div[2]/input").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".submit[value='Submit']").click()
```

Comment: Try Xpath `//input[@type="submit"]` or CSS selector `input[type="submit"]`. If it doesn't work, update your ticket with exception stacktrace

Comment: This works, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This does not work:
>
> driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='theform']/div[2]/input").click()
>   driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".submit[value='Submit']").click()

The first invocation likely does not work because the `input` descendant node is most likely too vague and ambiguous.

The second invocation doesn't work because `.submit[value='Submit']` is searching for (in english)

> Any element that has `class~="submit"` AND `value="Submit"`

The `value` attribute matches, but not the class selector.

You could find that element with a quick CSS selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']")
```

See [Effective CSS Selectors](http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html)  to see how to formulate good CSS selectors, and why this selector above would work.